# AVPlayer seek right after it starts to play

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I need to jump to particular time in audiofile right after it starts to play. So I use seekToTime method with completion handler

```
avPlayer.play()
```

...

```
avPlayer?.seekToTime(jumpTime, completionHandler: { isComplete in
    if isComplete {
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo![MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = CMTimeGetSeconds((self.avPlayer!.currentItem?.currentTime())!)
    }
})
```

The problem is that it needs time to start playing file from the internet. And for some reason the version of seekToTime with completion handler crashes the app, because it's invoked before avPlayer started to play. The version without completion handler works fine.

Error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'AVPlayerItem cannot service a seek request with a completion handler until its status is AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay.'
```

Is there a way to use a callback with `avPlayer.play()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

You need to observe changes in player:

```
avPlayer?.addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval(CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 3), queue: dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [weak self] time in
    self?.handleCallback(time)
}
```

And then you handle the state in the callback:

```
func handleCallback(time: CMTime) {    
   if avPlayer?.status == .ReadyToPlay {
       // place your seek logic here
   }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work exactly like that but I made it work. It didn't start to play. So I used seekToTime version without completion handler and placed the code from there into handleCallback()

Comment: Oh yeah, makes sense. Don't forget to remove the observer by calling `avPlayer?.removeTimeObserver(observer)` when you no longer need it :)

Comment: My code `seekToTime ` with completionHandler only crashes on iOS 10, but works fine on iOS 11, 12. Maybe it's Apple's bug?

Answer (score 3):

Please look at the Apple's answer for it:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1820/_index.html

```
    class MyClass {

    var isSeekInProgress = false
    let player = <#A valid player object #>
    var chaseTime = kCMTimeZero
    // your player.currentItem.status
    var playerCurrentItemStatus:AVPlayerItemStatus = .Unknown

    ...

    func stopPlayingAndSeekSmoothlyToTime(newChaseTime:CMTime)
    {
        player.pause()

        if CMTimeCompare(newChaseTime, chaseTime) != 0
        {
            chaseTime = newChaseTime;

            if !isSeekInProgress
            {
                trySeekToChaseTime()
            }
        }
    }

    func trySeekToChaseTime()
    {
        if playerCurrentItemStatus == .Unknown
        {
            // wait until item becomes ready (KVO player.currentItem.status)
        }
        else if playerCurrentItemStatus == .ReadyToPlay
        {
            actuallySeekToTime()
        }
    }

    func actuallySeekToTime()
    {
        isSeekInProgress = true
        let seekTimeInProgress = chaseTime
        player.seekToTime(seekTimeInProgress, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero,
                toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero, completionHandler:
        { (isFinished:Bool) -> Void in

            if CMTimeCompare(seekTimeInProgress, chaseTime) == 0
            {
                isSeekInProgress = false
            }
            else
            {
                trySeekToChaseTime()
            }
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: The link is very helpful and relevant to people dealing with this issue, but it could definitely use more explanation.